# Install Xscreensaver under V17.10

Tags: gnome, xscreensaver, 17.10

I've tried to install the Xscreensaver under 17.10 (Artful Ardvark) with no success. 17.10 uses Gnome, so the question is, I think, how do I install Xsceensaver under Gnome.

Comment: Could you provide some more info? What kind of error did you get? Did it install but failed to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple: I made a mistake in locating Synaptic. Once I found it, installing xscreensaver worked as expected. With one minor exception: the "rss" hack installed but isn't visible to xscreensaver. Every other hack (less BSoD - which I didn't install), including the GL hacks, works.

Executive summary: User Headspace Error

Comment: I got rss-glx working. Somewhere out there in the interwebs is a how-to. It's so simple I've forgotten it. Oops.